# angularjs ng-grid windows explorer displays thin rows but works properly in firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

If you look at this Plunker (which I didn't create)

http://plnkr.co/edit/fOMMXePQhWAF4DOnF3dW?p=preview

```
var ignoreThisCode = "I only put it here because to add a link to plunker it was required";
```

In Firefox version 31.0 it is displaying correctly, but in Internet Explorer Version 11.0.9600.16521 it is displaying very thin rows.

I have been using this example Plunker as a basis for a grid I am developing. I had been testing in Firefox and I thought all was good, but when I tried IE it was displaying wrong.

Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, in the main.js file, in the rowTemplate section an ng-style was setting height: 5, it needs to be 30 or what ever you want the row height to be.
I am not sure why it is working in Firefox though.

Answer (score 0):

In your `style.css`, remove `height: auto !important;` from `ngRow` class

Comment: I tried this suggestion, it does make the row height correct, but now the rows that are collapsed take up the same amount of room as if they are not collapsed.